# When is dispatch timer fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

In my iOS app I use GCD as a timer executed on a background thread. Here is my code:

```
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
double interval = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0);
uint64_t intervalTime = (int64_t)(interval * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, startTime, intervalTime, 0);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
   // some code
});

// start timer
dispatch_resume(timer);
```

I am wondering when the code inside the block is called. It is called every second (could happen that it is called even previous calling has not been finished yet) or it is called after one second from finishing previous calling?

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch_after works` just like a delayed `dispatch_async`. You still have no control over the actual time of execution nor can you cancel this once `dispatch_after` returns.

*Wondering when it’s appropriate to use dispatch_after?*

**Custom Serial Queue:** Use caution when using dispatch_after on a custom serial queue. You’re better off sticking to the main queue.

**Main Queue (Serial):** This is a good choice for dispatch_after; Xcode has a nice autocomplete template for this.

**Concurrent Queue:** Use caution when using dispatch_after on custom concurrent queues; it’s rare that you’ll do this. Stick to the main queue for these operations.

Go through [This documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) for more details